# Memory Management in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a question about reference counting.

This is my constructor:

```
- (id)initWithId:(NSString *)graphId;
```

In another class I make an object in the following way:

```
GraphViewController *graph =  
[[GraphViewController alloc] initWithId:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", current_ID];
```

My question is: how do I correctly release the string object?

Is it correct to release the string passed as a parameter?

Comment: yes, it is correct to release an object you're alloc'ing. if you alloc, you release, or autorelease if that value is returned from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never pass ownership around. I.e., in your call to initWithId: you create a string. Make sure it's released in the exact same place. Do not hand the ownership over, burdening another function with the task of releasing what you created (or retained, ...).

If you're not calling initWithId: an unusually high number of times per second, do an autorelease. Even better, use a convenience function. Do not let people talk you into "avoiding the autorelease pool". Because a) it's not so easy to avoid and b) you have more important things to worry about.

In code:

```
NSString* graphID = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", current_ID];
GraphViewController* graph = [[[GraphViewController alloc] initWithId: graphID] autorelease];
```

In the constructor, you will simply retain the ID and in the dealloc you will release it again. And please... use (private) @property declarations for this. You can then completely remove the ivar "graphID" from your public interface (if it's private, of course).

```
@interface GraphViewController ()
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* graphID; // copy instead of retain for potentially mutable objects
@end
```

Then, in initializer and dealloc, boilerplate stuff like:

```
@synthesize graphID;
- (id)initWithId:(NSString*) ID;
{
    self = [super init];
    self.graphID = ID;
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.graphID = nil; // controversial, Apple policy is [graphID release]; graphID = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Using this style will make you sleep better at night. Delighted users will raise statues in your name.

Answer (score 6):

Any of these ways will work:

(1)

```
GraphViewController *graph = [[GraphViewController alloc] initWithId:
    [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", current_ID] autorelease]];
```

(2)

```
GraphViewController *graph = [[GraphViewController alloc] initWithId:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", current_ID]];
```

(3)

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", current_ID];
GraphViewController *graph = [[GraphViewController alloc] initWithId: aString];
[aString release];
```

And, of course, `graph` needs to be released or autoreleased somewhere.

Comment: Okey, but in the third example, do I need to release the aString-argument in my constructor? Or is it sufficient to release graph? If you understand?

Comment: @Andreas Johannessen: In no case should another object need to release the arguments to its methods. The entire point of Objective-C's ownership system is to avoid that kind of complicated chain of responsibility.